# Javascript код не отправляет кастомные request заголовки

Tags: javascript, post

Создаю пробное API  на php 8.0 и apache2.
Столкнулся с проблемой, что php не воспринимает кастомные headers, созданные мною в js

```
async function functionToUpdate() {

const url = 'http://*ip*:8080/php/index.php';

const data = {
    email:'Frog@mail.ru',
    password:'password',
    phone:'+7123312344213',
    login:'Harry'
}

const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
headers.append("RequestType","registration");
fetch(url, {
    method:"POST",
    headers:headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(responce => responce.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error(error));
/*const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('RequestType','registration');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
xhr.onreadystatechange == function() {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(response);
    }
};

}
```

**php код**

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTION');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorisation-token,device_id,session_id");
header('Content-type: json/application');
header('Connection: Close');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

$type = getallheaders()['RequestType'];

if ($type === 'registration') {

    $login = getClearElement($_POST['login']);

    $password = getClearElement($_POST['password']);

    $phone = getClearElement($_POST['phone']);

    $postEmail = getClearElement($_POST['email']);


    require_once "./post/registration.php";
}
```

Проблема в том, что php код не видит RequestType ни в каком виде. Сам запрос воспринимается, однако header не виден. Даже в браузере не отображается.

Однако, если осуществлять данный запрос через postman, указывая в Headers RequestType, то код будет работать и обрабатывать.

Comment: если в браузере не отображается, то при чем тут пхп?

Comment: `header('Content-type: json/application');` ???

Comment: Ну и вообще а где обработка запроса `OPTIONS`? https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch-crossorigin#neprostye-zaprosy

Comment: И самый главный вопрос: зачем делать так сложно (да ещё и неправильно в PHP), что бы потом героически преодолевать проблемы? Обычный POST в формате `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` простой как палка и работает без всяких preflight запросах.
Ну и отдельно непонятно зачем это вообще запрос на другой домен…

Comment: @AlexeyTen А как правильно сделать? На другой домен необходимо, потому что сам php и apache находится на сервере (одном компе). А я открываю сайт и пробую это сделать на втором компьютере. Поэтому запрос идет на домен на котором лежит api.

Comment: @teran я предположил, что может быть и настройка сервера или сам код не правильны.

Comment: Комп на котором у тебя браузер вообще ни про чём. Сайт лучше бы сделать на том же домене что и PHP.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо за совет. Сайт делается на том же домене, что и PHP. Даже в 1м проекте. Однако если внутри кода js я укажу ссылку, как http://localhost:8080/****. То мне выдается ошибка о том, что сервер не хочет соединяться. 
Спустя время ошибка была исправлена, но возник новый вопрос. А точнее почему getallheaders() в php выводит warning, что RequestType не существует, однако сам обрабатывает код регистрации. А так же, console.log(ответ из сервера), выводит RequestType

Answer (score 0):

**Спустя несколько дней**

Внезапно код заработал. В php ничего не менял. Однако в js использовал вот такой код.

```
async function functionToUpdate() {

const url = 'http://*ip*:8080/php/index.php';

var RequestType = "registration";
var xhr = new FormData();
xhr.append('email', 'Frog@mail.ru');
xhr.append('password', 'password');
xhr.append('phone', '+123123123');
xhr.append('login', 'Froggger');

var xx = new XMLHttpRequest();
xx.open('POST',url,true);
xx.setRequestHeader('RequestType', 'registration');
xx.onload = function() {
    console.log(this.responseText);
}
xx.send(xhr);
}
```

Теперь регистрация проходит успешно.